# Python watchdog, moving a file triggers move event and modified event

Tags: python, directory, watchdog

Here is my FileHandler.. when I move a file, I get a move event and a modified event, but I only want a move event. How do I deal with this?

```
class FileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_modified(self, event):  
        print "path: " + event.src_path
        print "type: " + event.event_type
        print "is dir: " + str(event.is_directory)
        print "\n"

    def on_created(self, event):
        print "path: " + event.src_path
        print "type: " + event.event_type
        print "is dir: " + str(event.is_directory)
        print "\n"

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print "path: " + event.src_path
        print "type: " + event.event_type
        print "is dir: " + str(event.is_directory)
        print "\n"

    def on_moved(self, event):
        print "path: " + event.src_path
        print "type: " + event.event_type
        print "is dir: " + str(event.is_directory)
        print "dest_path: " + event.dest_path
        print "\n"
```

Comment: You can't because the file was both moved and modified.

Comment: Then how can I guarantee one case or the other?

Comment: That’s a tough question because watchdog does have its limitations. Try using another lib.

Comment: You can use Pyinotify for Linux and FileFirstChangedNotification for windows.

Comment: What do you mean you "only want a move event"? You get the events that actually occur. If you don't want all of them, you don't have do anything with them. Also, try using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can only have one event at the time, you have to play with SOU directory/file and DESTINATION